# How to hide part of agents in NetLogo 6.2?

Tags: netlogo

I have a 5x5 world with 10 agents in each patch in the world. I would like to hide almost everyone and only make one or 5 agents visible in the world to see their way. I only know how to do this by inspecting each agent in the interface and asking to hide it. But, I think there must be some easier way to ask to hide the 245 agents and make 1 or 5 agents visible in the world. Does anyone have any suggestions how I can do this?

Comment: A good practice is to always have the [NetLogo Dictionary](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html) at hand. For example, searching for "hide" would give you `hide-turtle`, which then also tells you to check `show-turtle` (i.e. the two commands that Steve suggested in his reply).

Answer (score 1):

Sure- there are turtle commands `hide-turtle` and `show-turtle`.

You could, for example, use this code either in setu or in a button on the interface:

```
 ask turtles [hide-turtle] ; hide all the turtles
 ask n-of 5 turtles [show-turtles] ; un-hide 5 of the turtles, selected randomly
```

Comment: I think I didn't express myself well. I have a world where agents are born in each patch in an orderly way from 0 to 9 in patch ( 0 0 ), from 10 to 19 in patch (1 0) etc... I would like to hide the previous 244 agents and leave the 5 last visible, ie the turtles 245, 246, 247, 248, 249. Is it possible?

Comment: @Rafaela The reply that Steve gave is fit for your question: you can use `hide-turtle` to hide all those agents, you just need to apply the command to your case - e.g. you need to ask those turtles to execute the `hide-turtle` command. If the structure of your model is such that turtles are created in a specific order, you can do so by combining `hide-turtle`, `min-n-of` and `who`. Depending on the case, one might say that this approach is not the most robust, however it might be enough for now.

Comment: I'm still trying to get a specific group of turtles to go underground. But I'm not getting it. I would like for example to hide turtle 0 to 4 then turtle 15 to 30        ask turtles [
    set turtle-list-hide ( list who )
    print turtle-list-hide
    set turtle-list-hide lput who [ 1 2 3 4 ]  turtle-list-hide
  ask turtle-list-hide [ hide-turtle ]
  ]  ;; turtle-list-hide (turtles-own)